# How to configure IntelliJ to use short package names on "Optimize imports" for a scala codebase?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, code-formatting, scalafmt

In a scala project where we are using IntelliJ community edition, we want to use multiple packages per file, so that we can reference them with shorter syntax:

```
package com.dreamlines.dragonfly
package api
package domain
package harbours

import common.entities.EsHarbour
import common.utils.date.DLDateTime
```

Yet IntellJ wants to enforce the fully qualified package name and hence on optimizing the imports it changes the code to:

```
import com.dreamlines.dragonfly.common.entities.EsHarbour
import com.dreamlines.dragonfly.common.utils.date.DLDateTime
```

How do I configure the behavior of optimize import?

It should

- at least keep the shortened imports or
- at best shorten the longer ones automatically

I want to keep the other behavior of optimize import intact, e.g. removing unused imports, adding missing imports, sorting imports. So I don't consider not using optimize imports a valid option.

---

We are furthermore using the `scalafmt` formatter, so it may relate to our `.scalafmt.conf` that looks like this for this project:

```
version = 2.0.0
style = default
maxColumn = 120
continuationIndent.callSite = 2
continuationIndent.defnSite = 2
align.openParenDefnSite = false
align.openParenCallSite = false
danglingParentheses = true
indentOperator = spray
project.excludeFilters = [".*\\.sbt"]
rewrite.rules = [RedundantBraces, RedundantParens, prefercurlyfors]
unindentTopLevelOperators = true
importSelectors = singleLine
spaces.afterKeywordBeforeParen = true
lineEndings = unix
newlines.penalizeSingleSelectMultiArgList = false
newlines.alwaysBeforeElseAfterCurlyIf = false
binPack.literalArgumentLists = false
runner.optimizer.forceConfigStyleMinArgCount = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is a code style option in IntelliJ that forces fully qualified package names. You can disable that and see if that helps: [image]